# How to keep usual spacing between words inserted conditionnaly

Tags: spacing, conditionals

Here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Titre}{Some text}
\newcommand{\Date}{and then some}

\begin{document}
        
    \ifdefined\Titre    \Titre    \else       \fi
    \ifdefined\Date     \Date     \else       \fi

\end{document}
```

Showing :

[image]

You see the text are not spaced. I saw I can arrange that by adding spaces inside the definition as such `\newcommand{\Date}{ and then some}` but it not the best way. Can you find a better one ?

Comment: all macros in text eats the space behind it. Use `\Titre{}` etc

Comment: You could add spaces inside the definition; e.g.  `\newcommand{\Titre}{Some text }`.  There is also `\space` and `~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Titre}{Some text}

\begin{document}
        
    Pre-Title \ifdefined \Titre\Titre{} \else\fi Post-Title
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might seem overkill, but reduces the amount of checking to the minimum.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printoneortwo}{mm}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \cs_if_exist:NT #1 { \seq_put_right:No \l_tmpa_tl { #1 } }
  \cs_if_exist:NT #2 { \seq_put_right:No \l_tmpa_tl { #2 } }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\Titre}{Some text}
\newcommand{\Date}{and then some}

\begin{document}

X\printoneortwo{\Titre}{\Date}X

X\printoneortwo{\foo}{\Date}X

X\printoneortwo{\Titre}{\foo}X

X\printoneortwo{\foo}{\baz}X

\end{document}
```

[image]

We add items to the sequence conditionally to the argument being a defined control sequence; due to `\seq_put:No`, the argument will be expanded just once.

Thus we get a sequence with zero, one or two items. Only in the last case a space is added between the items when `\seq_use:Nn` is executed.

Without `expl3` we can do

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printoneortwo}[2]{%
  \edef\@firstyes{\ifdefined#10\else1\fi}%
  \edef\@secondyes{\ifdefined#20\else2\fi}%
  \ifdefined#1#1\fi
  \if\@firstyes\@secondyes\space\fi
  \ifdefined#2#2\fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\Titre}{Some text}
\newcommand{\Date}{and then some}

\begin{document}

X\printoneortwo{\Titre}{\Date}X

X\printoneortwo{\foo}{\Date}X

X\printoneortwo{\Titre}{\foo}X

X\printoneortwo{\foo}{\baz}X

\end{document}
```

The space is added only if `\@firstyes` and `\@secondyes` are both 0, which aren't if at least one of the control sequences is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You can put spaces inside brace-nested macro-arguments:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Titre}{Some text}
\newcommand{\Date}{some more text}

\newcommand\fot[2]{#1}% first of two
\newcommand\sot[2]{#2}% second of two

\begin{document}

  \csname\ifdefined\Titre f\else s\fi ot\endcsname
  {%
    \Titre
    \csname\ifdefined\Date f\else s\fi ot\endcsname
     { and \Date}% <- Both \Titre and \Date are defined.
     {}% <- Only \Titre is defined.
     . %
  }{%
    \csname\ifdefined\Date f\else s\fi ot\endcsname
    {\expandafter\uppercase\Date. }% <- Only \Date is defined.
    {}% <- Neither \Titre nor \Date is defined.
  }%

\end{document}
```

The judegement whether this is a better way is up to you.